# AWS : Create application load balancer using cli/cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I want to create a script to automate creation of "application load balancer" in AWS.

I already have target groups details, subnets, etc.

I tried following this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-application-load-balancer-cli.html) but seems 'create-load-balancer' cmd does not have option of providing target group, subnets, etc.

Has oneone automated this? Is this possible?
Please share your thoughts/scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) which is also what ElasticBeanstalk uses to create load balancers.

It will allow you to define everything including subnets in JSON or YAML config files. You can do both the [application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html) and [target groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html).

Comment: thats pretty nice. Can we later edit alb properties? say need to edit subnet, etc.

Comment: Yep you can update your stack https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks.html